# ClassifierInformation's "ClassPriors" misreporting?

Tags: bugs, machine-learning

### To the **TLDR** people

It seems to me that when you explicitly set `ClassPriors` when running `Classify`, it creates a `ClassifierFunction` that works fine but reports the `Automatic` class priors instead of those explicitly provided. Is this true, intended, buggy, or am I missing something?

### To the **WHYTPPCWCCAPWWDWFY** people

*(What Have You Tried/Please Provide Code We Can Copy And Play With/We Don't Work For You)*

Take a `Classify` documentation example

```
data = {1 -> True, 2 -> True, 3 -> True, 4 -> True, 5 -> False, 
  6 -> True};

c = Classify[data];
```

It automatically chose Naive Bayes. Now we check the class priors

```
ClassifierInformation[c, "ClassPriors"]

(* <|False -> 0.25, True -> 0.75|> *)
```

Let's see the probabilites for 5

```
c[5, "Probabilities"]

(* <|False -> 0.341463, True -> 0.658537|> *)
```

This doesn't change if one explicitly sets the class priors, and this makes sense to me

```
c[5, "Probabilities", 
 ClassPriors -> ClassifierInformation[c, "ClassPriors"]]

(* <|False -> 0.341463, True -> 0.658537|> *)
```

Now, let's custom set other priors at classification time

```
priors = <|True -> 0.5, False -> 0.5|>;
c2 = Classify[data, ClassPriors -> priors];
```

The new probabilies lean more towards `False`, makes sense

```
c2[5, "Probabilities"]
c[5, "Probabilities", ClassPriors -> priors]

(* <|False -> 0.608696, True -> 0.391304|> *)
(* <|False -> 0.608696, True -> 0.391304|> *)
```

However, `ClassifierInformation` still returns the old priors

```
ClassifierInformation[c2, "ClassPriors"]

(* <|False -> 0.25, True -> 0.75|> *)
```

so these 2 now return different results.

```
c2[5, "Probabilities"]
c2[5, "Probabilities", 
 ClassPriors -> ClassifierInformation[c2, "ClassPriors"]]

(* <|False -> 0.608696, True -> 0.391304|> *)
(* <|False -> 0.341463, True -> 0.658537|> *)
```

Am I missing something when I find this weird/buggy?

Comment: Also, these machine learning functions seem to be very picky about receiveng the options/parameters as strings or as symbols. I most of mma, the string versions work even if the symbol exists, but not here. To make matters worse, ClassPriors is a symbol as an option and a string as a property (but not all properties are strings, such as `Method`). I'll probably report this since it is pointlessly annoying and inconsistent with other mma functions

Comment: I've reported it.

Comment: @rcollyer great, thanks!

Comment: Yup this is clearly a bug!

Comment: `GenomeLookup["WHYTPPCWCCAPWWDWFY"]` returns an error

Comment: @MichaelE2 I just intended to mean that that section was for those that would say too-long-didn't-read to a long post, and the second to those that would complain of a lazy incomplete question.

Comment: I'm just old-fashioned...And you got a complaint from the other side.  Can't please everybody. ;P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until the issue is fixed, you can observe that the provided ClassPriors are inside the ClassiferFunction (in some way):

```
ClassifierInformation[c,"Options"]
```

**Update**

This confused me as well when I first stumbled across it, but I have a utility function that I find quite useful for these `SubValue` type problems (as in the case of `ClassifierInformation` we don't have true `SubValues`):

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
propertyGrid[object:
Append[(Blank /@ Alternatives @@ GeneralUtilities`TextString`PackagePrivate`$elidedForms), _FittedModel],gridOpts : OptionsPattern[]] := Switch[object, _ClassifierFunction, 
Block[{props = DeleteCases[ClassifierInformation[object, "Properties"], "Properties"]}, 
Grid[({#1, ClassifierInformation[object, #1]} &) /@ props, Frame -> All, FilterRules[{gridOpts}, Options[Grid]]]], 
Append[(Blank /@ Alternatives @@ GeneralUtilities`TextString`PackagePrivate`$elidedForms), _FittedModel], 
Block[{props = DeleteCases[object["Properties"], "Properties"]}, 
Grid[({#1, object[#1]} &) /@ props, Frame -> All,FilterRules[{gridOpts}, Options[Grid]]]]]
```

Which gives a good overview of objects like `ClassifierInformation` and such:

[image]

Unfortunately ``` GeneralUtilities``TextString``PackagePrivate``$elidedForms ``` doesn't give an exhaustive (or entirely useful) list of `ElidedForms` that you might want to give to `propertyGrid` and there are **many** special cases I've not added. However, it's part of my tool box and I think relevant to the question.

Comment: Great, thank you

Answer (score 5):

This has been confirmed as a bug and reported by rcollyer.